# Flash player unresponsive google chrome?

Tags: actionscript-3, google-chrome, flash

Since while Google Chrome started to beehive strange with Adobe Flash Player.

I have a website, whole in flash technology. It is kind a heavy one, but everything was 
working fine.

About a month ago I started experience difficulties with Google Chrome browser. 
While website works for a more than 5-7 minutes it crashes. Sometimes it crashes even after start.

Popup message with "unresponsive" and asking to kill or wait for plugin.
I know that probably it is ActionScript error.

How to find the solution for this kind a errors? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be of some help.

http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/error-plug-unresponsive-google-chrome.html